# Words and lines counter from user input for Java

Tags: java, line, counter, cpu-word

I have done this code, it prints correctly the total number of lines but for the total number of words it always prints  total of 1 word. Can someone help me please, Thanks!

```
import java.util.*;

public class LineAndWordCounter{
  public static void main(String[]args){



    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(scan.hasNext()){
      String line = scan.next();

      linesCounter(scan);
      wordsCounter(new Scanner(line) );


    }


  }

  public static void linesCounter(Scanner linesInput){
    int lines = 0;
    while(linesInput.hasNextLine()){
      lines++;
      linesInput.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("lines: "+lines);
  }

  public static void wordsCounter(Scanner wordInput){
    int words = 0;
    while(wordInput.hasNext()){
      words++;
      wordInput.next();
    }
    System.out.println("Words: "+words);
  }




}
```

Comment: Are you supposed to input a number of lines, and when it's finished, count the number of lines and the number of words in that input?

Comment: @NomadMaker I tried using the same scanner for lines and words, the code will perfectly count the lines but when it is time to count the words the pointer will be at the end of the input and so there will zero words :(

Comment: Your functions takes the same type of parameter which is Scanner yet you send scan for linesCounter and new Scanner(line) for wordsCounter. Why?  I think you should pass the same scan object to your wordsCounter function and you should split received parameter according to whitespace. Then you can count each word in this specific line. Currently you only receive one line and iterate it only once with hasnext().

Comment: @ArdahanKisbet  I tried using the same scanner for lines and words, the code will perfectly count the lines but when it is time to count the words the pointer will be at the end of the input and so there will zero words.

Comment: When you count the lines, you read the entire line. You could take this String (line) and use String[] words = line.split(). This will give you an array and the length of the array ( words.length ) is the number of words in the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks rather complicated to me.

You can just save each line in an ArrayList and accumulate the words in a variable.
Something like this:

```
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
int words = 0;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scan.hasNext()) {
  String line = scan.nextLine();
  arrayList.add(line);
  words += line.split(" ").length;
  System.out.println("lines: " + arrayList.size());
  System.out.println("words: " + words);
}

scan.close();
```

You should also not forget to call the `close()` method o the `Scanner` to avoid a resource leak

Comment: Do not close the Scanner until there is no more use for it. Closing the scanner will also close the stream that feeds it. That's OK if it's a file because you can reopen a file. If it's System.in, it's not easy to reopen.

Comment: when `scan.hasNext()` returns `false` then there is no more use for the scanner, isn't it?

Comment: @Peter Lustig  Thanks so much! it does works it just need a little change:
System.out.println("lines: " + arrayList.size());
System.out.println("words: " + words);
Has to go out of the while loop to avoid printing everytime it loops.

Comment: You can also use `line.split("\\s")` or `line.split(StringUtils.SPACE)` from org.apache.commons.lang.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to add an extra dependency just for this.

Comment: I have a second question... I have tried the code with empty lines and it doesn't count the lines... is there a way to count the lines even though there is no words in it?

Answer (score 0):

```
scan.next()
```

returns the next "word".

If you create a new `Scanner` out of that **one word**, it will only ever see **one word**.

This will happen with

```
String line = scan.next();
wordsCounter(new Scanner(line) );
```

Comment: I can't find way to get all the words through the scanner :( because if I use the same Scanner for words and lines counting, just one of them will do right /